# Docker image crashing under heroku

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I recently published an OpenSource SSHFP tester tool as Dockerized container (https://github.com/dbsentry/sshfp). The tool works in docker and podman. I also setup a github actions to build a docker container and push the same to docker hub each time any file is committed to the repository.

The tool is basically flask API in the backend and Vue app as frontend. REST API is run using gunicorn and Vue is served using nginx.

For demo I am using Heroku. However, each time, I pushed and released the container to Heroku, using following commands:

```
[manish@getafix2 bin]$ docker tag dbsentry/sshfp registry.heroku.com/sshfp/web
[manish@getafix2 bin]$ docker push registry.heroku.com/sshfp/web
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/sshfp/web]
fa59c99d6036: Layer already exists 
ace0eda3e3be: Layer already exists 
latest: digest: sha256:824a5303c9b6a3e9b3f1bc1df19a9833f150c2a563d57abcf27e0b800083f6ad size: 740
[manish@getafix2 bin]$ ./heroku container:release web -a sshfp
Releasing images web to sshfp... done
[manish@getafix2 bin]$
```

However, each time I did that, it resulted in a crash with the following messages:

```
2020-12-02T17:38:04.365087+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (9b27af0ae5e8) by user manish@dbsentry.com
2020-12-02T17:38:04.365087+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user manish@dbsentry.com
2020-12-02T17:38:05.138252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-02T17:38:07.656483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/container/tools/run`
2020-12-02T17:38:10.642322+00:00 app[web.1]: *** CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL = 3 (info)
2020-12-02T17:38:10.645157+00:00 app[web.1]: *** In finally
2020-12-02T17:38:10.645343+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Killing all processes...
2020-12-02T17:38:10.726301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-02T17:38:10.780523+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

At first, I thought that this may be happening as Heroku does not allow you to hardcode port. So, I changed nginx config and set nginx config per the PORT environment variable.

I tried tracing the execution of `run` script but was unable to do so.

Any help to make this run in Heroku would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out Heroku expects a non-root user to run all the processes within the container. My tooling assumes a root user, which launches runit, and then changes user for each process (like a typical linux system does). So, I need to re-work my tooling for the Docker images so that it can also run as non-root user.